# Go through an array and delete the correponding columns

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I am a very beginner to VBA and I need your help for a specific task. In fact, I am trying to delete some of the columns of a table that have the same elements of an array. In order to do so, I created an array and ran a double loop to analyze each column header with the array.

```
Sub ClearColumns()
Dim Name As Variant, i As Variant, j As Variant
Name = Array("UniqueKey", "Item Type", "Path")
For j = 1 To 10
    For i = 0 To UBound(Name)
    If Columns(j) = Name(i) Then Columns(j).delete    
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

However, the If condition doesn't work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: `Columns` is the whole column so you need to refer to the first (?) row `cells(1,j)` perhaps ? Anyway, you can use Match to avoid having to loop.

Comment: Also you should delete starting from right to left... `For j = 10 to 1 Step -1`.

Comment: @SJR I actually need to delete the entire column if there is a match between the column header and an element of the array

Comment: @Toravin are the headers in row 1? I think the proposal is `If Columns(j).Cells(1, j) = Name(i)...`, so you are considering the *first* cell in the column.

Comment: Yes I realise that but one problem is this line `If Columns(j) = Name(i)` because you can't compare the whole column with a single value.

Comment: @BigBen Yes they are

Comment: You guys nailed it ! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a loop you can use MATCH (or FIND).

Also, no need to declare all variables as `Variant`, use a specific type where possible as it's more efficient.

```
Sub ClearColumns()

Dim Name As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, v As Variant

Name = Array("UniqueKey", "Item Type", "Path")

For i = 0 To UBound(Name)
    v = Application.Match(Name(i), Range("A1:J1"), 0) 'adjust range to suit
    If IsNumeric(v) Then Columns(v).Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: SUPER !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This works too actually:

```
  Sub ClearColumns()
  Dim Name As Variant, i As Variant, j As Variant
  Name = Array("UniqueKey", "Item Type", "Path")
  For j = 1 To 10
      For i = 0 To UBound(Name)
      If Columns(j).Cells(1, j) = Name(i) Then Columns(j).Cells(1, j).Delete
      Next i
  Next j
  End Sub
```

Comment: Better to delete from right to left as mentioned in the comments above. Otherwise there's the possibility that a column gets skipped. For example, if both columns 2 and 3 are to be deleted, once 2 is deleted then column 3 becomes the second column.